# How to bind list of dataframes ignoring dataframes with null values in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes that I want to use `bind_rows()` to combine all the dataframes. However, one of the dataframes is empty(no values only column names). When I try use `bind_rows(list)` I get an error "Cant combine character to a logical.

The only way I am able to combine them is by manually setting the empty dataframes = NULL. However, this is a very repetitive work as I need to find the index of the empty dataframes and then set them to null.

I am wondering if there is a parameter in bind_rows() that can ignore the empty dataframes and just combine that dataframes that have values.

Comment: Can't you just filter out your list to non-empty dataframes with an `lapply` - like `bind_rows(lapply(my_list, function(x) if(nrow(x) == 0) NULL else x))` ?

Comment: The problem is that the empty frame has a different structure (same column names, but different data types). That indicates a problem with the function that generates the list of data frames. The problem should preferably be fixed there.

Comment: Thanks @AllanCameron, actually filtering the list was a faster way to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved using lapply and filtering out the empty dataframes

`bind_rows(lapply(list, function(x) if(nrow(x) == 0) NULL else x))`